# How do I prevent a library to print to stdout (in Linux/C)?

Tags: c, linux, printf, stdout

I am using a library that prints all kind of crappy messages to stdout. I try to keep a clean output on my program, but that makes it impossible.

Any idea?

Comment: Don't use the _crappy_ library.

Comment: Compile the library with printf, fprintf, etc. defined as macros doing nothing.

Comment: What is that library?

Comment: Unfortunately is a supplier's library. No option to avoid the use of it. The library is also closed source, so no option to define macros for printf/fprintf.

Answer (score 1):

You can close() the stdout socket and then open a new socket to /dev/null (assuming pretty much anything but windows here).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int newfd;

    printf("good things come...\n");

    close(1);
    newfd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
    if (newfd != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "uh oh...  we didn't duplicate the socket properly\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("...to those that wait()\n");
}
```

And then running this you get:

```
$ ./test
good things come...
```

Note the no final line from printf.

[but I agree with the comments: using libraries that show signs of bad-things is probably a bad-choice for other reasons beyond the first one you spot]

Comment: As I said, there's no option to avoid that library. I wish there was... it's a big source of headaches!

Comment: You could use `dup2(newfd, 1)` instead of `close(1)` and hoping `newfd == 1`.

Comment: Hi sir, close(1)  works perfect, how to reopen the stdout again in the program ?